# Google Calendar API 403 Forbidden on event creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-calendar-api

I'm stuck and Googles documentation isn't any help at all.

I have authenticated the app with the appropriate scopes. I get the consent screen and the refresh token is stored correctly.

I'm able to view calendars on the user, but when I try to insert an event I get the 403 Forbidden error.

This is the code I'm using to add an event. (The same code was working before I added offline access)

```
UserCredential credential = GetCredential(user.Username);

if (credential != null)
{
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "OO Software Service System",
    });

    //Create the event.
    Event e = new Event()
    {
        Attendees = new List<EventAttendee> 
        {
            new EventAttendee() 
            {
                Id = user.GoogleId, 
                Email = user.Username
            }
        },
        Start = new EventDateTime()
        {
            DateTime = start
        },
        End = new EventDateTime()
        {
            DateTime = end
        },
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        Summary = eventName
    };

    //Insert the event into the calendar.
    e = service.Events.Insert(e, "primary").Execute();
```

Scope and Credentials:

```
public static string[] GetScopes()
{
    return new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, PlusService.Scope.PlusMe };
}

public static UserCredential GetCredential(string username)
{
    return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GetSecrets(),
        GetScopes(),
        username,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new ServiceSystemDataStore()).Result;
}
```

Is there anyone who can shed some light on what the problem could be? An error saying 403 Forbidden domain isn't exactly helpful.

I have of course enabled the necessary APIs in the Google Console and the scope is the correct one, since I get the refresh token by authenticating the user with the consent screen.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had the wrong `EventAttendee.Id`. This Id was provided when I authenticated the user, so I wrongfully assumed it was the supposed to be provided - I was wrong.

Sometimes you just have to write the question down to see the answer for yourself.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, when I include the `googleId` from auth response as `EventAttendee.id` I got an 403 response. What would be the right id to send?